# Displaying instances of view controllers within Xcode without disturbing the current hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viewcontroller, xcode-storyboard

I am producing an application written in swift in Xcode, I have reached a point in development in which I need to be capable of instancing views. Ideally I would alter the hierarchy of my program to contain a 'Main' or 'Parent' view, the main view would be responsible for displaying the views given to it.

Instancing other view controllers and passing the instance to the main view would be my goal, however, i am inexperienced with Xcode and swift, I am unsure how to go about including a main view without altering my entire storyboard hierarchy.

Here is an image to give a visual description of the current structure.

[image: Current Hierarchy]

The intention is to alter the hierarchy to include a main/ parent / master view, the view would be an empty display item which will display all views as and when needed, ideally I would keep the tab control method.

Mainly and most importantly the view will allow instances of view controllers to be displayed, closed and refreshed without impacting other aspects of the app.

Code seems irrelevant here as my views are handled by the storyboard. Something which would be really helpful to me here would be a brief explanation of how I can handle instancing with the new hierarchy.

Thank you in advance for any help regarding this matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view controller can serve as a custom parent view controller of one or more child view controllers, displaying their views in any desired manner within its own view's interface.

---

You can instantiate a view controller in any desired manner. If you wish to pluck a view controller instance out of the storyboard (because you have already designed its view there), call:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboard/1616214-instantiateviewcontroller

Your view controller in the storyboard will need to have a storyboard ID string so that you can identify it.

---

After you've plucked a view controller from the storyboard in that way, to display its view in your interface, you must do the following dance:

1. The parent calls https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621394-addchild
2. The parent captures the view controller's `view` and sticks it into the interface as a subview of the parent's own view.
3. The parent calls https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621405-didmove

The two view controllers now stand in a legal parent-child relationship and both view controllers will work properly. They can even refer to one another.

If you wish to remove the child view controller's view from the interface, you must reverse the dance:

1. The parent calls https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621381-willmove with a `nil` parameter
2. The parent removes the child view controller's view from the interface
3. The parent calls https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621425-removefromparent

---

Please read "Implementing a Container View Controller" on the main view controller docs page:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller

Comment: Thank you for your helpful response. Im going to read through the links you have sent ill mark this as solved once I have. Thank you for taking the time to respond

Comment: one question on this, where would the container view sit within the hierarchy? and will my tab and nav bars remain unaffected. The links are really useful thank you for your explanations

Comment: I should add that if what I'm describing is in fact what you want to do, what you want to do is _totally_ legitimate. It is absolutely right to manipulate subviews that are owned by a child view controller, and even to divide up the whole interface in to clumps each of which is governed by its own view controller. View controllers should be _small_ and agile, and use of a parent with child view controller(s) can facilitate this.

Comment: I am assuming that one of your existing view controller _is_ the container view. (Your question is not sufficiently specific for me to assume anything else — not your fault, since you don't know the terms for the things you are trying to imagine).  If you want to cover the whole interface with a completely separate dominating view controller's view, that is a fullscreen presented (modal) view controller.

Comment: Currently, all views are simply view controllers which where originally navigated via segue and buttons. I realised upon attempting to refresh a view that I'm not following a good design pattern for what I need to achieve. Having a view which is in control of what is displayed is what I need here while ensuring my navigation methods are still valid.

Comment: Take a quick look at my Albumen app. The top level is a navigation controller with standard master-detail architecture. Except that it isn't, because you can switch between navigation controllers. How?  There is a custom parent / container view controller that is really the top level.

Comment: Thank you ill take a look at that now @matt

Comment: Hi @matt I couldn't find the albumen app, im trying to determine where I would put the master controller in my program. I think I understand the other concepts of parenting views etc. I am concerned that I will disrupt the current navigation and tab controllers within the application.

Comment: Sorry but that's entirely up to you; you might ask a different question. I believe I've answered the question you actually asked, namely how a view controller's view can make itself responsible for the display of another view controller's view.